# Why doesn't the rename command work as expected?

Tags: debian, rename

I have some files like:

```
1_suffix.txt
2_suffix.txt
3_suffix.txt
```

I want to remove the `_suffix.txt` in them. I found a command called `rename` and use it as:

First I tried:

```
rename -v 's/*_suffix.txt$/\.txt/' *.png
```

It's not working, but later I tried:

```
rename -v 's/_suffix.txt$/\.txt/' *.png
```

It worked.

I think the second regexp is incorrect but why it worked?

I tried use ls:

```
ls _suffix.txt # not worked
ls *_suffix.txt # worked
```

Comment: Your version of `rename` must be completely different from mine. On my machine `rename _suffix.txt .png *.txt` works  (part/replacement/files) while regexp is not supported at all. (rename from util-linux 2.26.2).

Comment: @ThomasErker the OP is using perl rename which is the default on debian-based systems. You might be able to find it on your system as `prename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rename` command takes regular expressions, not glob patterns. While `*foo` is a valid glob pattern, it is not a valid regular expression. The `*` means "0 or more" but you also need to specify 0 or more *what*. For "any character", use `.`:

```
s/.*_suffix\.txt$/.txt/
```

Now, the next issue is that `s/_suffix.txt$/\.txt/' *.png` will never work. You are telling `rename` to rename all files whose name ends in `_suffix.txt` but are telling it to do this to files whose name ends with `png`. That's what the `*png` (which is a glob and not a regular expression) means.

I think what you really wanted is:

```
rename 's/_suffix//' *suffix.txt
```

That will replace `_suffix` with nothing, it will simply delete it, which should give your files the name you want.

Comment: Actually, it takes Perl expressions.  It's Perl's substitution operator (`s///`) that takes a regular expression (and a replacement; usually a string). :)

Comment: @TheSidhekin yes, I know. It takes Perl Compatible Regular Expressions. My point is that perl-rename needs a regex and the OP was giving it a glob.

Comment: Not "Perl Compatible" – "Perl"!  It's running perl: `rename 'BEGIN { print $^X, "\n" }' /` yields `/usr/bin/perl`. :)

Comment: @TheSidhekin yes, I know. The type of regular expressions that Perl uses are called PCREs (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions), that's their name. Granted, in Perl, you can just call them Perl regex, but PCRE is a widely used and recognized regex class. Just like ERE and BRE.

Comment: No, Perl uses its own, original (not very) regular expressions.  The C library called PCRE implements its own, original (not very) regular expressions.  In spite of the name, they are not identical:  Perl's regexen have capabilities PCRE's don't have, and PCRE's have capabilities Perl's don't have.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions#Differences_from_Perl

Comment: @TheSidhekin ah, I see, thanks. I always thought that Perl also implemented PCREs.

Answer (score 0):

[Path name glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)) used by Unix shell are different from [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in syntax and meanings of meta characters.